# Count the number of times a word appears in a file

Tags: linux, file

What is an easy way to count the number of times a word appears in a file?

Comment: How do you define 'word'? Is it just a string, or a string surrounded by spaces, a string surrounded by a set of characters? What characters can these be?

Comment: a 48 charactors string, no space and no special charactors other than ascii

Answer (score 146, accepted):

This will also count multiple occurrences of the word in a single line:

```
grep -o 'word' filename | wc -l
```

Comment: Ahh, the `-o` does the magic. Nice answer, never knew that. No more upvotes today though :(

Comment: past the test, why cat the file, then it count the multiple word on the same line?

Comment: the reason i want to know is for the performence since we have large log files lots of them to count those jsession id, very painful, need count those fast, but well done, so far i like this one the best, thx mohit6up!

Comment: Good Answer: I don't see this documented  in man.  How did you find out ?

Comment: @twalberg That doesn't work for repeated words in a line. I just tested on a mac.

Comment: @mohit6up Yeah, I noticed that after I posted. The way around that is to either split lines into one word each - there's a couple solutions posted along those lines - or utilize something based on python/perl/whatever instead. I don't think `grep` can provide a full solution to this one... My comment was really meant to point out that the `wc -l` bit was unnecessary, but I probably should have stated that explicitly...

Comment: `grep -ow word file | wc -l` if you care for [word boundaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71537/201820).

Answer (score 3):

```
cat filename | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'word' | wc -l
```

Comment: This approach is very inefficient.  `cat` is not really needed here.  `tr ' ' '\n' < filename | grep -cw 'word'` would do.

Answer (score -1):

```
fgrep "word to be counted" filename|wc -w
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wants.