# Single-line bash command that will count and display the occurrences of a particular string in a file

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I am a Bash & Terminal NEWBIE. I have been given the task of counting the number of entries of a specific area code using a single-line Bash Terminal command. Can  you please point me in the right direction to achieving this goal? I've been using a [bash scripting cheat sheet](https://devhints.io/bash) but i'm not familiar enough with bash commands to create a script to iterate and count the number of times [213] appears in file:

Comment: Do you want a line like `213 and second 213` be counted as one hit (most answers) or as 2 hits (answer of @jeremysprofile) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the string `123` anywhere in the file, then:

```
grep -c 123 file # counts 123 4123 41235 etc
```

If you are looking for the "word" 123, then:

```
grep -wc 123 file # counts 123 /123/ #123# etc., but not 1234 4123 ...
```

If you want multiple occurrences of the word on the same line to be counted separately, then use the `-o` option:

```
grep -ow 123 file | wc -l
```

---

See also:

- [Confused about word boundary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71537/201820) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

grep -o '213' filename | wc -l

In the future, you should try searching for *general* forms of your command. You would have found a [number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-text-file-with-the-comma) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889882/linux-command-what-is-an-easy-way-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-word-appears-i) [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398413/counting-occurrences-of-word-in-text-file)

Answer (score 1):

See `man grep`. `grep` has a `count` option.

So you want to run `grep -c 213 file`.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you here too.(It will look for string `213` anywhere in the line(s) of Input_file)

```
awk /213/{count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```

In case you want to look for only those lines which have exactly have digit `213` then use following.

```
awk /^213$/{count++} END{print count}' Input_file
```